# Dynamically setting the color of LinearProgress in older MUI versions

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working on a legacy React with MUI project and I want to use this css to set a LinearProgress' color based on a percentage `backgroundColor: hsl(${percentage}, 100%, 50%`

```
 "react": "^16.3.1",
 "@material-ui/codemod": "^1.1.0",
 "@material-ui/core": "^3.4.0",
 "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
```

The issue is, that I started this component as a functional component and would rather not change it back to a class component, since the actual component is a bit more complex than my example below.

```
const MyLinearProgress = ({props}) => {
  const { percentage } = props;
  return (
    <LinearProgress
      variant='determinate'
      value={ percentage }
      style={{
        height: '35px',
        border: 'black solid 0.5px'
      }}
      classes={{
        // this is currently blue
        barColorPrimary: 'blueStyle',

        // this is white
        colorPrimary: 'whiteStyle'
      }}
     />
}
export default MyLinearProgress;


.blueStyle {
  background-color: blue;
};
.whiteStyle {
  background-color: white;
};
```

This way I can successfully set any color, but I'd like to change it via the hsl function based on my props dynamically whenever the props change. The `sx` prop would be perfect for this, but this is an old version.

Any ideas except upgrading MUI? I would really love to upgrade but sadly it's not an option.

The time frame I have is too small to just make a component myself from scratch, since the one colored LinearProgress is already in production and this was supposed to be just a small feature.

Thanks!